# Fragment management in Android - how to prevent old fragments' text in the background?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I added a menu with some actions, which are handled in MainActivity as well. For example after firing the 'Logout' menu action, MainActivity method 'onOptionsMenuSelected()' want to forward to LoginFragment. Unfortunately the text elements of the former fragments are still showing up, altough I am calling replace() of FragmentTransaction to change the relevant fragment to show in my forwardToLoginFragment() method. What needs to be done to hide old fragments and their content successfully?

Moreover, sometimes my app stops, because FragmentManager tries to add a fragment to the activity more than once. This results in an app crash. How to manage the fragments wisely to prevent this issue as well?

Excerpts of my MainActivity class:

```
private void forwardToLoginFragment(){
    LoginFragment loginFragment = (LoginFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(LoginFragment.LOGIN_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if (loginFragment == null){
        loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
        ft.add(R.id.container, loginFragment, LoginFragment.LOGIN_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    } else {
        ft.replace(R.id.container, loginFragment);
    }
    ft.commit();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        ...
        case R.id.menu_main_signout:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Signing out ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setSignedIn(false);
            forwardToLoginFragment();
            return true;
        ...
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Screenshot is batter illustration to solve an issue of UI/Ux so please put it and update your question

Comment: Why don't you giving tag (as third parameter) here  ft.replace(R.id.container, loginFragment);

Comment: Hi Mahesh B13, 

I thought it makes no difference adding the String as a third parameter to the replace method. I currently gave it a try.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, unfortunately I am not able to start the virtual device here, so I am not able to make a screenshot. Anyway I hope everybody will be able to imagine the picture of overlying strings or fragments.